# jQuery syntax to animate translateZ

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I've got a div set up with a CSS `.scroller` class:

```
.scroller {
    position: relative;
    perspective: 150;
    -webkit-perspective: 150;
}
```

It contains divs that have their `translateZ` properties set by jQuery, simulating depth. That all works fine.

What I'd like to do now is animate the Z property from one value to another, but I can't seem to find the right syntax. I keep getting a 'Unexpected Identifier' error in the console. Amongst various combinations of speech marks and apostrophes, here is what I've tried:

```
$('#artist' + scrollerCounter).animate({-webkit-transform: translateZ(-40px), transform: translateZ(-40px)}, 1000);
```

Is it even possible to `.animate` the `translateZ` property?

Comment: This may be a work around, but I've managed to indirectly set translateZ with .css(), using the step function. Each time the .animate step function is triggered I set the element's .css('transform', 'translateZ('+valueHere+'px)');